# How do I extract list of files from a magnet link or .torrent?

Tags: utorrent, magnet-links

While I understand I can view the list of files contained within a .torrent or a magnet link, is there anyway I can extract / copy the list of files for sorting etc.?

For example, a torrent that has over a thousand files from where I wish to choose what I want / don't want. Browsing through that list one by one becomes tedious, so I was wishing for a way where these filenames could be put inside notepad etc. where I could sort them via extension and other criterion.

utorrent does not seem to allow this.

Answer (score 3):

There are command line utilities to show the contents of torrents, e.g. [intermodal](https://github.com/casey/intermodal) (`imdl torrent show`).

If you have a magnet link, you first need to download the corresponding torrent file from a swarm somehow, because the magnet link on its own doesn't have this information. There are also command line utilities for this, e.g. [ih2torrent](https://github.com/elektito/ih2torrent).

Comment: Thank you, :-) I will try these and get back.

Comment: I tried taking a look at your suggestions. Too difficult for an end user like me. But thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to what has been written:

We will have to download some part of torrent so they reflect filenames completely in a folder so that is waste of time and bandwidth. And then if you we on linux then we can use print option to list all files from that folder.

If not then, we would go to source torrent page and see all list of files included in a torrent, more than 95% torrent trackers be it private or public have list of files included in torrent page. We would simply copy paste that. Even if on public trackers we can't find list of files from one site we can take hash info and find same torrent under other sites and see the list of files included. Every site has different style of presentation so it should be easy for you to get filenames likewise.